# Symfony2 form validation without createFormBuilder

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.4

I am trying to validate the form that I have made myself in **.twig** file.I am not creating form using `createFormBuilder`. This is my Controller Code that is call for both case **1) for view 2) after submitting the form**.

```
public function cart_newAction(Request $request)
 {      
    $entity = new Product();
    $errors = '';
    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') 
    {
        $validator = $this->get('validator');
        $errors = $validator->validate($entity);
        if (count($errors) > 0) {
            echo 'Error';
        } 
        else {
            echo 'Success';             
        }
    }
    return $this->render('CartCartBundle:Cart:Add.html.twig', array('errors' => $errors ));
}
```

this is view file and I am showing errors like this
**`Add.html.twig`**

```
{% for error in errors %}
    {{error}}
{% endfor %}
```

I have set the error in validation.yml file for name that cannot be blank.
So now when I run the view page it every times show the error after I submit the form.
If no error it should not display me the error just show the blank error.

`Note:`Is there any better way that I can do this so please share it.Remember that I am doing it without `createFormBuilder` 
**UPDATE**
It always show me Error.Even if my form is valid and don't missing any field.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @xdazz actually I want the form validation I am not using the `createFormBuilder` so how can I do this.The work that I have done is not working properly

Comment: `not working properly` is just not enough to describe your problem. Could you describe the detail.

Comment: Error is not disappeared when I don't miss the form fields.It should not show the errors but it is always giving the error even the first time when I view the page it show error there too.

Comment: Where is the code you set the entity property?

Comment: The Above code I have set in the DefaultController

Comment: Unless I am missing something, I cannot see where you are binding your entity to your request in your controller method, so as far as I can see from the above code you are validating an newly created (i.e: empty) entity.

Comment: Do you have the formType for your entity ? because if you have it you can validate more better your form.

Comment: Could you @Azam Alvi Werlich please accept or vote for my answer if you think it solved your problem or was the most helpful in finding your solution. Thank you. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make the form yourself then you can't validate it using the Syfmony form validator. You  need to use a simple PHP validation Server-side. Something like this

```
if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') 
{
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    if ($username == '')
    {
       // set error message here
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok let me be clear. I gonna give you tow solutions, the first is the best and the most proper way:
1) Generate your EntityForm Type: `bin/console make:form` or `d:g:form` command.
2) Then just add some few lines to submit and get the errors.

```
 public function cart_newAction(Request $request)
 {      
    $entity = new Product();
    $form = $this->createForm(EntityType::class, $entity);
    $form->submitForm($request->request->all(), false);

    if ($request->getMethod()->isPost()) 
    {
    if ($form->isValid()) {
            echo 'Error';
        } 
        else {
            echo 'Success';             
        }
    }
    return $this->render('CartCartBundle:Cart:Add.html.twig', [
         'errors' => $form->getErrors(),
    ]);
}
```

The second solution is bind your data into your entity object because we need to set the data into our object.

1) First step create a `private` fonction in your current class to bind all the submited data:

```
private function bindEntityValues(Product $entity, array $data) {
  foreach ($data as $key => $value){
    $funcName = 'set'+ucwords($key);
    if(method_exists($entity, $funcName)) $entity->$funcName($value);
  }
}
```

Then your cart_newAction should be like this:

```
 public function cart_newAction(Request $request)
 {      
    $entity = new Product();
    $this->bindEntityValues(entity, $request->request->all());
    $errors= $this->get('validator')->validate($entity)

    if (count($errors) > 0) {
            echo 'Error';
        } 
        else {
            echo 'Success';             
        }
    }
    return $this->render('CartCartBundle:Cart:Add.html.twig', ['errors' => $errors]);
}
```

Wish this helped you to have a clear vision.

Answer (score 0):

You must check if `$errors` is empty or not :

```
if (count($errors) > 0) {
    return $this->render('CartCartBundle:Cart:Add.html.twig', array('errors' => $errors ));
} else {
    return $this->render('CartCartBundle:Cart:Add.html.twig');
}
```

See the doc [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#using-the-validator-service).